# visual c++ runtimes, should they be installed or not?

Tags: visual-c++, runtime

Regarding the Visual C++ Runtimes. Is it a good idea to manually install all the VC Runtimes so when an app requires it, it will have it ready so it won't need to install it? If not then why?

Answer (score 2):

It shouldn't really matter. Any application that needs them should be distributing it with its installer. Installation should only take a few seconds anyway. But if you desperately want to have them already installed, go ahead. The disk space requirements should be next to insignificant nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

The installer should contain the VC redistributables if they need them. Windows will install them into the applications SxS assemblies folder.

For security, updates to the runtimes are released via Windows Update. Installing a later version of the runtimes (2005/2008/2010) doesn't make the previous version more secure because they're disparate runtimes that correspond to the version of Visual C++ that the application was compiled with.